# ORACLE DATE FILTER NOT SHOWING CORRECT DATE RESULT

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have data as

```
ID      MYDATE
1       2020-02-02 19:45:00:00
1       2020-02-02 20:00:00:00
```

I need to get data of only min_date.

So I have used  query as (considering eastern and utc time zone)

```
 SELECT  ID, MYDATE 
    FROM MYTABLE
     WHERE TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(MYDATE.'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS'),'YYYY- 
   MM-DD HH24.MI.SS), 'AMERICA/NEW_YORK) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYYMMDD') = 
    '20200202'
```

I get result for 2020-02-02 (which is expected)

```
1   2020-02-02 19:45:00:00
```

But when  I run for date '20200203' I am getting

```
 1      2020-02-02 20:00:00:00
```

which I should not be getting( I shouldn't be getting any results)

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What's the data type of the column? What's the time zone or time offset of those values in the table?

Comment: I guess that MYDATE is not a date, right ?

Comment: MyDate column data type 'date'

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with daylight savings time?

Comment: Correct we have to take care for daylight savings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 2 rows of sample data it is ... challenging to give the solution that you are looking for. But here is a query that gives you the row with the lowest date for an id:

```
WITH tab (id, mydate) 
AS
(
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('2020-02-02 19:45:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL union
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('2020-02-02 20:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL  
),
ordered_dates AS
(
SELECT 
       id, 
       mydate, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY mydate) AS rn FROM tab
)
SELECT id, TO_CHAR(mydate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM ordered_dates WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

AMERICA/NEW_YORK timezone is UTC -4, so when you convert AMERICA/NEW_YORK to UTC, you get
original time + 4 hour,ie `2020-02-03 01:00:00 UTC`:

```sql
WITH t (id, mydate) 
AS
(
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('2020-02-02 19:45:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL union
  SELECT 2, TO_DATE('2020-02-02 20:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL  
)
select
  TO_CHAR(MYDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS') original_time,
  FROM_TZ(
     TO_TIMESTAMP(
        TO_CHAR(MYDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS')
       ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS'
     ),
     'AMERICA/NEW_YORK'
   )
   AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
    as UTC_TIME
from t;

ORIGINAL_TIME       UTC_TIME
------------------- --------------------------------------
2020-02-02 19.45.00 2020-02-03 00:45:00.000000000 UTC
2020-02-02 20.00.00 2020-02-03 01:00:00.000000000 UTC

2 rows selected.
```

And you do not need `to_timestamp(to_char(...` in this case, it's easier to use CAST:

```sql
FROM_TZ(cast(MYDATE as timestamp),'AMERICA/NEW_YORK') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Comment: @anonymous ok, great